# How to run Appium tests in Visualstudio Appcenter

Tags: appium, mstest, visual-studio-app-center

I have written all the UI automation tests for my Android app in Appium with C# and MSTest. Currently these tests are being run in Browserstack.

I would like to replace browserstack with VisualStudio Appcenter but couldnt find any documentation to run my C# Appium on Appcenter. Does Appcenter support this combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Appium Testing on VS App Center only supports tests written with Java (on both Android or iOS devices).

If this is a feature you'd like to see in future, I would recommend registering on [Vistual Studio App Center](https://appcenter.ms) and then if you look in the bottom right there is an icon to open a dialog in Intercom - you can request features here and it will be routed to the correct department before being recorded as a feature request.

Comment: See also [issue 102](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/102) on app center's github repo about Appium in C#.